# Preferred method to alter jQuery UI stylesheets?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I need to make a few tweaks to only the following elements

*from jquery.ui.autocomplete.css*

- ui-autocomplete
- ui-menu
- ui-menu-item

*from jquery-ui-theme.css*

- ui-widget
- ui-widget-content
- ui-corner-all

Do you recommend I directly make the changes to jquery-ui-theme.css and jquery.ui.autocomplete.css or would you recommend I make my own .css file with the changes to those 6 elements, and then put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="newstyles.css">
```

as the LAST item in `<head></head>`?

Comment: Yup, just do what you suggested. I usually leave alone the original ui files and create a new css to just overwrite those rules.

Comment: I'm with @elclanrs on this one. Creating a new stylesheet makes migrating to a new version much easier, since you won't lose your modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that it's best to leave the 3rd party css files as they are, and then create a second file that overrides those values. Just make sure that you include the files in the correct order so that your changes take effect.

The reason I find myself doing this is so that if I want to upgrade to a newer version that has updated css, I don't have to patch the rules again to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I'd always recommend against editing core files of any framework or theme, just for safety.  In your case, I'd definitely make a new sheet with the changes.  That way, if you ever need to update, debug, or change your theme, your customizations will remain separate and intact.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own css to override whatever it is you wanna override, this will make it easier to upgrade in the future when new versions come along.